# How to create a lecture Reminder in Android

Tags: java, android

Please i need an idea how I can design a lecture Reminder that shows lectures a students have for a day.  And a countdown timer to for the next lecture..  In Android..  I need a coding idea, a guide could be better.. Am new in new in Android programming.  I have a screen shot of interface I designed  [screen shot of lecture Reminder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJBg1.jpg) ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJBg1.jpg)

Comment: SO is not a site to ask for someone to write the code for you, you have to try yourself, and when you face a problem, you can ask about it

Comment: I didn't ask for code...  I needed a structure..  And someone just gave me that..  Av gotten wanted

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an ambitious enterprise for the first contact with Android programming. I would suggest something simpler.Anyway, you have to:

- provide configuration interface to define lectures, and to manage them (e.g. change their schedule)
- organize long-term storage for lecture-related data
- provide application logic to find the next lecture
- deliver notifications to the user, including acknowledging them or perhaps re-sending them if not acknowledged

Quite a lot to learn.

Comment: Thank.. Work began in earnest